# NHibernate using ODBC to connect to ASA 9.0 pops windows on taskbar

Tags: nhibernate, odbc, sybase-asa

I'm using NHibernate in a project where I need to access to different types of databases using DSNs. I configure NHibernate to use the following parameters:

```
connection.probider: DriverConnectionProvider

dialect: GenericDialect

connection.driver_class: OdbcDriver
```

The connection string I pass it contains the DSN with a UID and password. Now most of the times the database used is either a MS-SQL database or an ASA 9.0 database.

Everything works fine, but when I connect to an ASA 9.0 database, **I get a new icon on the Windows Taskbar** (like if there was a new Windows application opening) that comes and goes **whenever there is an exchange with the database**.

This icon has the name `MyDatabase - Adaptative Server Anywhere - 9.0.x.y`, where `MyDatabase` is the name of my database and `x.y` are version numbers I don't remember.

**Does someone know if and how I can prevent those?**